# I need a delay inside Recursion function in android but Handler Delay breaks the Recursion Function

Tags: java, android, handler, timertask

[image]

I'm creating a tower of Hanoi simulation in Android(Java), using the tower of Hanoi recursion algorithm.
every this works fine all the disks instantly move from source to destination tower.
The problem occur when I tried to **put a delay inside the recursion Function** to make its moves slowly, so I can see moving its every step but `Handler.Postdelayed` just break the Recursion

**Any Fix for this Code Or other Suggestions to Delay the UI Changes**

```
void hanoi(int disk, int source, int dest, int aux) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(disk ==1){
                autoClick(source,dest);
            }
            else {
                hanoi(disk - 1, source, aux, dest);
                autoClick(source,dest);
                hanoi(disk - 1, aux, dest, source);
            }
        }
    }, 100);}
```

Comment: You should put delay in `autoClick` instead of `hanoi`. It is `autoClick` which do the moves, not `hanoi`. Delaying `hanoi` makes no sense.

Comment: But note that you are putting delay on a task but not waiting for it, you should calculate the delay time base on which step it is, e.g. first step delay 100ms, second step delay 200ms, etc. Otherwise you have to implement a callback pattern to start the next task only after the previous task is execute.